# ionic 2 home page accidentally replace

Tags: ionic2

I'm developing an Ionic 2 project and I already had a page called "home", so I had to create another page and did the command "ionic g page home", so my actual page "home" was replaced. Is there any chance to get my "home" back? The visual studio code editor don't have history and I can't restore in windows too

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think it were permanentty delete. Try to find it in Recycle Bin. If it is not in there, i think there is no way to restore it